# Delegate Methods in Swift for UIPickerView

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Just getting started in Swift and having trouble calling the delegate methods for a UIPickerView

So far I have added the UIPickerViewDelegate to my class like so:

```
class ExampleClass: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate
```

I have also created my UIPickerView and set the delegate for it:

```
@IBOutlet var year: UIPickerView
year.delegate = self
```

Now I am just having trouble turning the following into Swift code:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 12):

That's actually a method in the `UIPickerViewDataSource` protocol, so you'll want to make sure you set your picker view's `dataSource` property as well: `year.dataSource = self`. The Swift-native way seems to be to implement protocols in class extensions, like this:

```
class ExampleClass: UIViewController {
    // properties and methods, etc.
}

extension ExampleClass: UIPickerViewDataSource {
    // two required methods

    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }
}

extension ExampleClass: UIPickerViewDelegate {
    // several optional methods:

    // func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, widthForComponent component: Int) -> CGFloat

    // func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, rowHeightForComponent component: Int) -> CGFloat

    // func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String!

    // func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, attributedTitleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> NSAttributedString!

    // func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusingView view: UIView!) -> UIView!

    // func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)
}
```

Comment: Using an extension to implement a protocol is nice because it encapsulates all the code related to the protocol in one place, and if you change your mind about it in the future, you know exactly what you can remove :)

Comment: Exactly! And since `#pragma` is gone and the `// MARK ...` method doesn't work yet, it's kind of the only way to organize things at the moment. ;)

Comment: Nate. Using this way how would I make sure that my UIPickerView is being used?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow - you'll need to have added the pickerView to the view of your view controller, in IB or in code, and you'll need to implement enough of the delegate methods to provide content for the rows of the picker view (probably at least the `titleForRow, forComponent` method).

Comment: Got it. Normally in the titleForRow method you can do something like "return array[row]" how would you do that in Swift?

Comment: Exactly like that - you'll likely want to have a `String[]` array somewhere so you can return titles for each row and the length for number of rows in component...

Comment: Right now I have an array and am trying to return [array objectAtIndex] but not sure how to do so in swift.

Answer (score 0):

The delegate isn't responsible for calling that method. Instead it is called by the UIPickerView's data source. These are the two functions called by the UIPickerView data source that you need to implement:

```
// returns the number of 'columns' to display.
func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!) -> Int

// returns the # of rows in each component..
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int
```

To ensure these functions get called, your class should also implement the data source protocol:

```
class ExampleClass: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource
```

And your picker's data source should be set:

```
year.dataSource = self
```